# How to update Tweepy Streaming Python code

Tags: python, tweepy

I had this code running for an earlier version of Python but now want to upgrade it to the latest version of Python and Tweepy however I cant seem to make it work.  Any help would be much appreciated!  The error I get is:

ImportError: cannot import name 'StreamListener' from 'tweepy.streaming' (C:\Users\mmanenica\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py)

```
import sys

from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN = ""
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
          wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = pd.DataFrame(columns=['description', 'location', 'text', 'name', 'user_created', 
                  'followers', 'user_id', 'created', 'retweets', 'analysis', 'sentiment'])

class Listener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, output_file=sys.stdout):
        super(Listener,self).__init__()
        self.output_file = output_file
        self.counter = 0
        self.limit = 3
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            name = status.user.screen_name  
            sleep(randint(100,190))
            print(name)
            api.create_friendship(name)            
            
            print(status.text, file=self.output_file)
                 
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter <= self.limit:
                print(self.counter)
                return True
            else:
                print('Limit reached')
        except:
            print("Error in adding friendship")                   
        
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print('Error ' + str(status_code))
        return False

listener = Listener()

stream = Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=listener)
try:

    stream.filter(track=['NFTs', 'Buying NFT', 'Buy NFT', '-filter:links', '-filter:retweets'])

    print('Start streaming.')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopped.")
finally:
    print('Done.')
    stream.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have installed the last version of tweepy (4.5.0). You can guarantee this by typing in your terminal `pip install --user --upgrade tweepy`. You can try it without the `--user` part. It should upgrade too.
Now, with the latest version installed, you can start to collect a stream with some code like the following (based on https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming.html):

```
import tweepy 

class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)


stream = StreamCollector(
  "Consumer Key here", "Consumer Secret here",
  "Access Token here", "Access Token Secret here"
)
stream.filter(track=["Obama"])
```

Note that `on_data` method recieve the raw_data directly from Twitter. We are just printing it with the code above, but you can treat this `data` object like a python dictionary and extract whatever information about the tweets that you want.

I suggest, instead of printing the `data` object, something like the following (import `json` library and put the rest of the code inside `def on_data`, instead of `print(data)`):

```
import json

tweet_info = json.loads(data)
print(tweet_info['text'])
```

Note that we have accessed the `data` object and extracted only the tweet ' text ' information. You can go deeper and access other informations from the `tweet_info` dictionary and also complement the code above with your necessities showed in the question.

Hope it helped. :)

Comment: Yes thank you.  The Stream Collector function is what I needed.  I was already on the latest version of Tweepy and I am using the latest version of Spyder.